# How should equality be defined for C++ iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I'm implementing a directed graph data structure, where edges live in two simultaneous linked lists: The list of a vertex's outgoing edges, and the list of the opposite vertex's incoming edges.

I've defined iterators over incident edges, which traverse either list.

My question is this: How should I determine whether the  iterators are equal? Should they compare equal iff they point to the same edge, or should they compare equal if they point to the same edge **in the same list**?

That is to say, should `i == j` imply that `++i == ++j` and `--i == --j` (same position in the same traversal)? Or is it sufficient that `&*i == &*j` (reference the same object in memory)?

Which would be most consistent with the invariants/expectations for, say, STL iterators?

Comment: `&*i == &*j` would exhibit undefined behavior for begin iterators of empty containers and always UB for end iterators

Comment: IMHO, yes, the equality operator should be applicable to iterators (and pointers).  This way you can test if two iterators refer to the same item.  This is normal, such as comparing an iterator to *container*.end().

Comment: UB == *undefined behavior*.

Comment: A lot would depend on how you're going to use the comparison.  But I think a guiding principle could be if you increment both iterators and they end up pointing to different elements of the container, they're not equal - even if they're pointing to the same element right now.

Comment: @273K: Ah. Assume that syntax means "underlying pointer comparison" (which would not in general be expressible without private member access, but hopefully you get the idea)

Comment: To add to my previous statement (which I now see you proposed in the question) I'd say the principle of least surprise demands that the increment/decrement order be the same after the iterators compare equal.

Comment: And if you'll allow me to inject even more confusion into my ramblings, I note that the standard provides forward and reverse iterators that may compare equal even while they iterate in opposite directions.

Comment: The convention for forward and reverse iterators may be the disambiguating case that I need. That suggests that they should pointer compare!

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't think you can compare a forward iterator directly to a backward one. The `operator==` overloads all take only the reverse iterator and are templated so that implicit conversion won't work.

Comment: Hm, I've just confirmed by experiment in c++20 that `std::vector`'s forward and reverse iterators are not comparable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard's notion of a *forward iterator*, which is an iterator for a sequence that can be iterated over multiple times, requires that if `i` and `j` with `i == j` are dereferencable iterators (i.e. not one-past-the-end of value-initialized), then also `i++ == j++`.

It also requires that `i == j` iff either both `i` and `j` are not dereferencable or both are dereferencable and `*i` and `*j` refer to the same object.

However, in the standard the domain considered for `==` is that over a *single* sequence. All of the iterator properties always only apply over one specific sequence. Comparing iterators for different sequences generally has no specified behavior (i.e. UB in the standard library).

Of course, nothing stops you from extending that concept to cover `==` between multiple sequences, but that's not going to be anything that standard library algorithms or other libraries using the standard's iterator concept are going to be able to make use of.

In which way you extend `==`'s meaning is then up to you. That's going to depend on how you want to use the functionality.

Comment: I think I'll lean towards "pointer" comparison, then; since that would allow (for example) a loop to forward-traverse until it hits an iterator found by backwards traversal. Intuitively, pointers also compare equal if they refer to the same object, and it seems right for iterators to have pointer-like behavior.

Comment: @user17732522, the "and only if" expression in the sentence "It also requires that `i == j` iff and only if" can be removed.

Comment: @LoS Fixed, seems I wasn't sure whether I wanted "_iff_" or "_if and only if_" there.